# get information from dataset (json format) in r

Tags: json, r, mongodb

I created a datatable from mongodb collection. Data in this datatable is in JSON format but I cant get to extract the information from it..

> {"place":{"bounding_box":{
>            "type":"Polygon",
>            "coordinates":[
>               [
>                  [
>                     -119.932568,
>                     36.648905
>                  ],
>                  [
>                     -119.632419,
>                     36.648905
>                  ]
>               ]
>            ]
>         }}}

I need the first two values of the coordinates: lat = 36.648905 and lon = -119.932568

But cant seems to extract that info:

```
my_lon <- myBigDF$place.bounding_box.coordinates[1[1[1]]]
```

I have tried few combination but I'm always getting NULL.
Thank you for any help..

--EDIT-- Including the code on how I'm connecting to db and creating dataframe from it..

```
mongo <- mongo.create(host="localhost" , db="mydb")

library(plyr)
## create the empty data frame
myDF = data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## create the cursor we will iterate over, basically a select * in SQL
cursor = mongo.find(mongo, namespace)
## create the counter
i = 1

## iterate over the cursor
while (mongo.cursor.next(cursor)) {
  # iterate and grab the next record
  tmp = mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(cursor))
  # make it a dataframe
  tmp.df = as.data.frame(t(unlist(tmp)), stringsAsFactors = F)
  # bind to the master dataframe
  myDF = rbind.fill(myDF, tmp.df)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly how you are going from the JSON string to an R object. There are different libraries that parse thing differently. If I assume for a moment use "rjson", then you would have something like

```
x <- rjson::fromJSON('{"place":{"bounding_box":{ "type":"Polygon", "coordinates":[ [ [ -119.932568, 36.648905 ], [ -119.632419, 36.648905 ] ] ] }}}')
```

And because your data seems to have an excessive number of square brackets, things are a bit messy. You can get to the coordinates section with

```
x$place$bounding_box$coordinates
# [1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] -119.9326   36.6489
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] -119.6324   36.6489
```

which is a list of lists of vectors. To make a nice matrix of lat/long coordinates you can do

```
do.call(rbind, x$place$bounding_box$coordinates[[1]])
```

Comment: @MrFlink Thanks I did try that approach but I'm still getting NULL - I have edited the post and included the code on how I'm creating the data frame. Thanks again..

Comment: The code isn't helpful because we can't run it so we have no idea what it returns. At that point you don't appear to be interacting with JSON at all which is confusing because that's primarily how you described your data. I guess you would need to share `dput(myDF)` to have some idea of what type of data structure you are really working with.

Comment: dput(myDF) gave me class = "data.frame" but when I do my_lon <- myBigDF$place.bounding_box.type it works and returns Polygon. Also, tried x <- rjson::fromJSON(myDF) but getting an error "unable to escape string. String is not utf8". Thanks